# Any way to change the incremental save behavior?

Tags: config

I'm using Blender 4.0.2 on Windows 10.    I'm working on a project where I have multiple blend files representing different parts of the project, like

```
proj_shot1a
proj_shot2b
proj_shot3a
proj_shot3b
```

etc.   I love Blender's "incremental save" feature but it doesn't just append a number to the existing project name.    It seems to look through the whole project name and if it finds a number **anywhere** it increments that number and calls it good.   This breaks my "shot numbering" system because `proj_shot1a` then becomes `proj_shot2a` and then `proj_shot3a`, and so on.

Is the incremental save feature configurable anywhere?  I have looked and I don't see anything like this, but I'm hoping it's buried somewhere in a submenu.

Ideally "incremental save" would add a number to the **end** of the file name, so "proj_shot1a" would become "proj_shot1a_001" and so forth.

Any Blender wizards out there have an answer for this?

Comment: I have no real solution for you - but first I thought you want something like automatically incrementing the letters at the end. If it is okay for you that Blender adds "_001", why don't you just start by adding "_000" after your first file's name? When you name it "proj_shot1a_000.blend", then Blender does not increment **any** number it finds and for example make the next one "proj_shot2a_000.blend", but it will continue with "proj_shot1a_001.blend", "proj_shot1a_002.blend" and so on... which it should "ideally" do as you said - it only needs you to start different.

Comment: That simple change did exactly what I needed.   Thank you!   Proof that sometimes a second pair of eyes on a problem is critical to solving it.